# How can I get my encoded number onto a new line with easygui?

Tags: python, base64

I want to get the `base64encode(ntei)` onto a new line under "Heres the number in base 64: ", does anyone know a way?

```
import easygui as e

nte = e.enterbox(msg="Enter Number to convert", title="", default="", strip=True)
ntei = int(nte)

def base64encode(number, alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"):
    """Converts an integer to a base64 string."""
    if not isinstance(number, (int, long)):
        raise TypeError("Number must be an integer")

    base64 = ""
    sign = ""

    if number < 0:
        sign = "_"
        number = -number

    if 0 <= number <len(alphabet):
        return sign + alphabet[number]

    while number !=0:
        number, i = divmod(number, len(alphabet))
        base64 = alphabet[i] + base64

    return sign + base64

def base60decode(number):
    return int(number, 64)

print e.msgbox(msg=("Heres the number in base 64: " + base64encode(ntei)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `"Heres the number in base 64: " + base64encode(ntei)`. You are not putting a newline there yourself, so naturally it doesn't display one. Newlines are represented via the character `\n` in Python. So to add a newline to that string, we must change it to `"Heres the number in base 64:\n" + base64encode(ntei)`.

It is also worth mentioning that your base64encode function is completely unnecessary (as is using `print` in front of `easygui.msgbox`, unless for some reason you wanted to see that function's return value). You can convert a string to base64 via the encode method of Python strings, as in `ntei.encode('base64')`. Using this knowledge, your entire program can be rewritten to the following:

```
import easygui as e

nte = e.enterbox(msg='Enter number to convert', title='', default='', strip=True)
e.msgbox(msg=('Heres the number in base 64: ' + nte.encode('base64')))
```